# Acceleration of a Mass in Pulley Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

A 3 kg mass and a smaller mass are hung from a pulley and released. The 3 kg mass accelerates down at 5 m/s^2.

Picture :

[image]

Question: Find the smaller mass.

Here is the work I have so far.

[image]

I know what the answer is. However, I was wondering how I know the acceleration is 5 m/s^2. I know that this is acceleration for the heavier mass, but how do I know it is the same for the lighter mass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the string has constant lenght $L$. This means that if one the bodies moves $ΔS$, the other one must move the same $ΔS$ so that the lenght of the string remains constant at $L$. If one the masses had more acceleration than the other, they would move different distances in the same interval of time $Δt$, and therefore the sum of the lenghts of the string on each side of the pulley would no longer add up to $L$, meaning the string must have changed lenght. Since the ideal string doesn't stretch, this can't happen. Therefore, both accelerations must be the same. (Actually, both accelerations must have the same absolute value, but you get the idea. One accelerates upward while the other accelerates downward).

Another way to look at this is using conservation of energy in an ideal string. Since the ideal string has no mass and no ellastic potential energy, the work it receives must equal the work ($W$) it does.
Since $W = FΔs$, and the force (tension $T$) is constant along the string, we may conserve energy by seeing that the string does work (lifting the lighter mass) while it receives work (is pulled down by the heavier mass). This leads to:
$$TΔs = TΔs'$$
Therefore
$$Δs = Δs'$$
And the accelerations therefore have the same absolute value.